# Updating multiple tables inside cursor not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two records in a table A. This helps me to update table 2 however the update is not been applied. This is the SQL code where I added a validation section that allow me to determinate the problem.

```
DECLARE abc CURSOR FOR
select d.cod_suc, d.cod_ramo_comercial, d.nro_pol, d.cod_item, d.cod_ramo_tecnico, d.cod_tarifa,
d.id_stro, d.nro_stro, d.fec_hora_reclamo, d.fec_aviso, d.fec_registro, d.fec_ingreso_contable,
d.txt_place_of_accident, d.id_substro, d.txt_nombre_cober, d.txt_direccion_bien_siniestrado, d.txt_descripcion_perdida, d.txt_cheque_a_nom, d.cod_manager_code, d.importe_pago_eq
from table1 d
where d.fec_hora_reclamo between '20140801' and '20150731'
and (d.cod_suc = 2 and d.cod_ramo_comercial = 255 and d.nro_pol = 1000001 and d.cod_item = 5)

OPEN abc
FETCH abc INTO @cod_suc, @cod_ramo_comercial, @nro_pol, @cod_item, @cod_ramo_tecnico, @cod_tarifa,
@id_stro, @nro_stro, @fec_hora_reclamo, @fec_aviso, @fec_registro, @fec_ingreso_contable,
@txt_place_of_accident, @id_substro, @txt_nombre_cober, @txt_direccion_bien_siniestrado, @txt_descripcion_perdida, @txt_cheque_a_nom, @cod_manager_code, @importe_pago_eq


WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    select @varIDPV = min(id_pv), @varCodTarifa = min(cod_tarifa)
    from #portfolio p
    where p.cod_suc = @cod_suc and p.cod_ramo_comercial = @cod_ramo_comercial and p.Poliza = @nro_pol and p.Item = @cod_item and p.cod_ramo_tecnico = @cod_ramo_tecnico
    and p.[ID Incident] IS NULL

    /**************************************************************************************************************
    -- Validation section
    -- First record:
        mid(id_pv) = 100, min(cod_tarifa) = 1
    -- Second record:
        mid(id_pv) = 100, min(cod_tarifa) = 1
        --> Should be mid(id_pv) = 100, min(cod_tarifa) = 2
    */
    select min(id_pv), min(cod_tarifa)
    from #portfolio p
    where p.cod_suc = @cod_suc and p.cod_ramo_comercial = @cod_ramo_comercial and p.Poliza = @nro_pol and p.Item = @cod_item and p.cod_ramo_tecnico = @cod_ramo_tecnico
    and p.[ID Incident] IS NULL
    /**************************************************************************************************************/

    update p set p.[ID Incident] = @id_stro, p.[No. Incident] = @nro_stro,
    p.[Fecha Accidente] = @fec_hora_reclamo, p.[Fecha Notificacion] = @fec_aviso, p.[Fecha Registro] = @fec_registro, p.[Fecha Pago] = @fec_ingreso_contable,
    p.[Lugar Accidente] = @txt_place_of_accident, p.[ID Subsiniestro] = @id_substro, p.[Cobertura Amparo] = @txt_nombre_cober, p.[Direccion Bien Siniestrado] = @txt_direccion_bien_siniestrado, p.[Descripcion Perdida] = @txt_descripcion_perdida, p.[Pago A] = @txt_cheque_a_nom, p.[Referida] = @cod_manager_code,
    [Incurrido R12] = @importe_pago_eq, [Incurrido Cerrados R12] = @importe_pago_eq
    from #portfolio p
    where p.cod_suc = @cod_suc and p.cod_ramo_comercial = @cod_ramo_comercial and p.Poliza = @nro_pol and p.Item = @cod_item and p.cod_ramo_tecnico = @cod_ramo_tecnico
    and p.[ID Incident] IS NULL and p.id_pv = @varIDPV and p.cod_tarifa = @varCodTarifa

    FETCH abc INTO @cod_suc, @cod_ramo_comercial, @nro_pol, @cod_item, @cod_ramo_tecnico, @cod_tarifa,
    @id_stro, @nro_stro, @fec_hora_reclamo, @fec_aviso, @fec_registro, @fec_ingreso_contable,
    @txt_place_of_accident, @id_substro, @txt_nombre_cober, @txt_direccion_bien_siniestrado, @txt_descripcion_perdida, @txt_cheque_a_nom, @cod_manager_code, @importe_pago_eq
END

CLOSE abc
DEALLOCATE abc
```

When I see the result, only the first record is updated.

Comment: Have you checked to see if @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 after the 1st iteration completes?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually as you can see, in the validation section the cursor returns the two records but update the query to get min values returns the same data. I think due to update is inside cursor the commit is done after DEALLOCATE

Comment: Theres so much to this query its hard to tell.  Your 2nd fetch inside the while loop may be pulling the exact same data into abc as your initial fetch?

Comment: The table A allways comes with NULL value for [ID Incident] field. So I evaluate the min values where this field = NULL then update. When the cursor fetch the second record must be evaluate the same [ID Incident] = NULL but it is getting the first record once again although the update was done in the first fetch. As you can see it is like the first record has not been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot to add one condition more in update (inside where). Thanks for the support